# Is there any way to use RNGCryptoServiceProvider class in C# Portable class Library

Tags: c#, cryptography, portable-class-library

I am working on a encryption algorithm and using cryptography for this. I want to make this portable, but didn't find any way to resolve this class.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the full managed Bouncy Castle Library. A Portable Class Library Patch is available here: http://www.bouncycastle.org/jira/browse/BMA-107

A pre-build of Bouncy Castle 1.7 with the PCL Patch is available here for example: https://github.com/dnauck/Portable.Licensing/tree/master/lib

Answer (score 1):

You Didn't mention what profile you are looking for

In any case...
  RNGCryptoServiceProvider  it seems to exist only in

.NET Framework
Supported in: 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0
.NET Framework Client Profile
Supported in: 4, 3.5 SP1

As per documentation at [RNGCryptoServiceProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx)

I started dealing with cryptography, with [pclContrib](http://pclcontrib.codeplex.com/) 
but I didn't find it complete enough, basic functionality I needed to calculate some hashes
worked fine as far I stick to what pclcomtrib had,

But then it got a little messy with the references in the projects mostly with the Silverlight side because these are adapters [PCLContrib FAQ](http://pclcontrib.codeplex.com/documentation) .

*I ended up abstracting all the security bits using interfaces within the pcl's
where the implementations are platform specific*

pretty much the same thing you might face with file access (depends how portable you want to go).

I'm afraid pclcontrib  might not be your case too

```
Portable.Security.Cryptography    
 System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged
 System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1
 System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
 System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed
 System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed
 System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes
```

You might want to have a look at the following questions/answers that I think will (indirectly)answer your question.

[Questions tagged portable-class-library with Cryptography keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bportable-class-library%5D%20cryptography)

Answer (score -1):

You may want to check out http://pclcontrib.codeplex.com. It has support for cryptography.