# Where is RNGProvider in Window Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, nuget-package, rngcryptoserviceprovider

I am developing an SDK (Nuget Package) for Windows Phone 8.1. I already have a version for Windows Phone 8 where there is a use of *RNGCryptoServiceProvider*. But while developing for Windows Phone 8.1, I discovered that this class is no more availble in *System.Security.Cryptography* (now *Windows.Security.Cryptography*).

Please does anyone knows where this class is located now? If not present at all, how can I get a similar service?

Thanks.

Comment: Also this may be relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294383/is-there-any-way-to-use-rngcryptoserviceprovider-class-in-c-sharp-portable-class

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the Windows Phone 8.1; you may use PCL version of Bouncy Castle - for example: https://github.com/dnauck/Portable.Licensing/tree/master/lib